# Applying batch process with ModelBuilder in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, batch, iteration

I have done a process in a **Model Builder** in **ArcMap 10.5 version** and in order to execute it once over a lot of rasters I have used raster iteration.

It works well, but I cannot  specify differents parameters to each raster such as do a clip with differents shape.. So I want to know if **can we use the batch option in ModelBuilder**.

I add a picture with a part of my model, if it is another way to do the iteration you can suggest me ( the labels are in spanish but only is important the iteration -hexagon shape box-).

[image]

Comment: By "the batch option" do you mean by "using the [batch grid](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/a-quick-tour-of-batch-processing.htm)"?

Comment: Yes, using the batch grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use model tools that you build using the ModelBuilder in the batch grid.

However, I would not guarantee that you will get the results that you expect.

Two Q&As that suggest there may be issues doing that are:

- [Does Calculate Value (Model Only Tool) work correctly in tools run in Batch?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36891/does-calculate-value-model-only-tool-work-correctly-in-tools-run-in-batch)
- [Unexpected result using ModelBuilder in batch?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178553/unexpected-result-using-modelbuilder-in-batch)

I suspect that you may be better doing this using ArcPy rather than ModelBuilder.